# What causes the failure to upload an image in Firebase Store in this React 18 app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a **chat app** with React 18 and Firebase 9.

I run into a problem while developing an *image upload* functionality for the "Register" form.

In `src\firebaseConfig.js` I have:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth();
export const storage = getStorage();
export const db = getFirestore();
```

In the `src\pages\Register.jsx` component, I have:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import md5 from "md5";
import FormCard from "../components/FormCard/FormCard";
import { make } from "simple-body-validator";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db, storage } from "../firebaseConfig";

export default function Register() {
  const initialFormData = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    avatar: "",
    password: "",
    password_confirmation: ""
  };

  const validationRules = {
    firstName: ["required", "string", "min:3", "max:255"],
    lastName: ["required", "string", "min:3", "max:255"],
    email: ["required", "email"],
    avatar: ["required"],
    password: ["required", "min:6", "confirmed"],
    password_confirmation: ["required"]
  };

  const validator = make(initialFormData, validationRules);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

  // Form validation errors
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(validator.errors());
  // Firebase errors
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const [pristineFields, setPristineFields] = useState(() =>
    Object.keys(initialFormData)
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const newFormData = { ...prevFormData, [name]: value };
      const newPristineFields = pristineFields.filter((f) => f !== name);

      validator.setData(newFormData).validate();
      const validationErrors = validator.errors();
      newPristineFields.forEach((f) => validationErrors.forget(f));
      setErrors(validationErrors);

      setPristineFields(newPristineFields);

      return newFormData;
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!validator.setData(formData).validate()) {
      setErrors(validator.errors());
    } else {

      const email = formData.email;
      const password = formData.password; 
      const successContainer =  document.getElementById('successAlert');
      const errContainer =  document.getElementById('errorAlert');

      try {
        const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        // Hide error
        errContainer.classList.add('d-none');

        // Show success
        successContainer.classList.remove('d-none');

        // Create avatar filename
        const date = new Date().getTime();
        let userAvatar = formData.avatar ? md5(`${formData.email}-${date}`) + `.${formData.avatar.split('.')[1]}` : 'default-avatar.png';
        const storageRef = ref(storage, userAvatar);

        // Upload image
        await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, formData.avatar).then(() => {
          getDownloadURL(storageRef).then(async () => {
            try {
              // Update profile
              await updateProfile(response.user, {
                avatar: userAvatar,
              });

              // Store user
              await setDoc(doc(db, "users", response.user.uid), {
                uid: response.user.uid,
                firstName: formData.firstName,
                lastName: formData.lastName,
                email: formData.email,
                avatar: userAvatar,
              });
            } catch (error) {
              setError(true);
              console.log(error)
            }
          })
        })

      } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
        errContainer.append(error.message);
        errContainer.classList.remove('d-none');
      }
    }

    setPristineFields([]);
  };

  return (
    <FormCard title="Register">
      <div id="errorAlert" class="d-none text-center alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
        {error}
      </div>

      <div id="successAlert" class="d-none text-center alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
        You have registered successfully! 
      </div>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div
          className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has("firstName") ? "has-error" : null
            }`}
        >
          <label for="firstName" className="form-label">
            First name
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            value={formData.firstName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control form-control-sm"
          />
          {errors.has("firstName") ? (
            <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first("firstName")}</p>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div
          className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has("lastName") ? "has-error" : null
            }`}
        >
          <label for="lastName" className="form-label">
            Last name
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="lastName"
            name="lastName"
            value={formData.lastName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control form-control-sm"
          />
          {errors.has("lastName") ? (
            <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first("lastName")}</p>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div
          className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has("email") ? "has-error" : null
            }`}
        >
          <label for="email" className="form-label">
            Email address
          </label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control form-control-sm"
          />
          {errors.has("email") ? (
            <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first("email")}</p>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div
          className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has("avatar") ? "has-error" : null
            }`}
        >
          <label for="avatar" className="form-label">
            Avatar
          </label>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="avatar"
            name="avatar"
            value={formData.avatar}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control form-control-sm"
          />
          {errors.has("avatar") ? (
            <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first("avatar")}</p>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div
          className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has("password") ? "has-error" : null
            }`}
        >
          <label for="password" className="form-label">
            Password
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control form-control-sm"
          />
          {errors.has("password") ? (
            <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first("password")}</p>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div
          className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has("password_confirmation") ? "has-error" : null
            }`}
        >
          <label for="password_repeat" className="form-label">
            Confirm Password
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password_repeat"
            name="password_confirmation"
            value={formData.password_confirmation}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control form-control-sm"
          />
          {errors.has("password_confirmation") ? (
            <p className="invalid-feedback">
              {errors.first("password_confirmation")}
            </p>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div className="pt-1">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-success fw-bold">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </FormCard>
  );
}
```

The form data is submittit successfully, as seen below.

#### The problem

The image that should be uploaded in Firebase Storage, is of type "application/octet-stream" instead of "image/jpeg" and is under 10B.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata),

> If no contentType metadata is specified and the file doesn't have a file extension, Cloud Storage defaults to the type 'application/octet-stream'.

```js
const meta = { contentType: 'image/jpeg' };

await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, formData.avatar, meta).then(() => {
    getDownloadURL(storageRef).then(async (url) => {
        try {
            // Update profile
            await updateProfile(response.user, {
                avatar: url,
            });

            // Store user
            await setDoc(doc(db, "users", response.user.uid), {
                uid: response.user.uid,
                firstName: formData.firstName,
                lastName: formData.lastName,
                email: formData.email,
                avatar: userAvatar,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            setError(true);
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
})
```

On the other hand, looks like only the file path string is only uploaded to Firebase and not the entire file.

**Corrected:**

- Remove 'value=' parameter to file as it not needed.

```jsx
<input
  type="file"
  id="avatar"
  name="avatar"
  onChange={handleChange}
  className="form-control form-control-sm"
/>;
```

- Check if there is any file from the input *onChange* event.

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value, files } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const newValue = files?.length > 0 ? files[0] : value;
      const newFormData = { ...prevFormData, [name]: newValue };
```

- Remove validators and get the file name properly.

```jsx
let userAvatar = formData.avatar
          ? md5(`${formData.email}-${date}`) + '.' + formData.avatar.name.split(".")[1]
          : "default-avatar.png";
```

Comment: Edited the answer. Have a look.